# Error when trying to link to Dropbox Account from phone using Dropbox core API

Tags: android, dropbox-api

Why is there this error: This URL is not valid! Are you sure your app secret is correct?

shown when I try to link to my Dropbox Account from my phone using Dropbox core API, after I enter my username and password? I checked and all the app_secret which I input is correct.

Comment: What's the exact error message you're getting? Is the exact text "This URL is not valid! Are you sure your app secret is correct?" Also, could you share the URL where you're seeing this message (but X out any secrets you have in that URL)?

Comment: Yes that is the exact error message shown on the phone when trying to load this URL: https://www.dropbox.com/1/connect?locale=en_GB&k="KEY_XX"&s=&state="Random_numbers"

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? If you're not using the latest (currently 1.3.10 for iOS and 1.6 for Android) you should upgrade to that first and try again: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks  If that doesn't help, this is probably something Dropbox API support should help with: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm using version 1.6. Have contacted Dropbox API support, awaiting reply.

Comment: @shannon Did you get any further with this?

Comment: Nope, I just replied to the dropbox API support email which asked me about the SDK version which I am working on.

Comment: @GrahamBorland I managed to solve the problem using the following solution (posted below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted Dropbox API support and was recommended to use OAuth 2 instead of OAuth 1. For example, use startOAuth2Authentication instead of startAuthentication in your Dropbox code.

I have tried it out and it worked! I am now able to link to Dropbox from my account. Thanks to Dropbox Support.